# Url parameters extraction

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
```

could u please explain what exactlly is happening in the above line of code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is extracting all get parameter from url

Comment: Modified your tags as there is no jQuery being used.

Answer (score 5):

- You create a variable with a name of `results` to be scoped to its execution context.
- You invoke the `RegExp` constructor thereby instantiating the object and pass a string to be used as the regex. You have to do it this way because you can't concatenate regex literals with outside data.
- The regex says match any of `\`, `?` or `&` followed by `name` variable, and then literal `=` and then make a capturing group of every character besides `&` or `#`, 0 or more times.
- You call the `exec()` method on the new `RegExp` object, with `window.location.href` (the current URL) as its argument.
- The return of this is assigned to your `results` variable.
- The capturing group's contents (if successful) will be in `results[1]`.

*or*

You are getting a GET param by its name :)